# Как в Delphi сделать окно всегда неактивным

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, firemonkey

То есть даже при нажатии кнопки внутри окна оно само не должно становиться активным. Подходит любое решение, через WinAPI в том числе.

Фреймворк FMX

Comment: Какую задачу решаете?

Comment: Аналог экранной клавиатуры в windows с другим поведением кнопок. Чтобы нажатие проходило в окно, оно должно быть активным. А у меня окно клавиатуры перехватывает фокус. Уже пробовал активировать другое окно через AppActivate из SNDKEYS32.PAS, а также вызывать Deactivate в событии OnActivate

Comment: Пару часов копал в сторону MFC: там есть метод ModifyStyleEx, но я пока не знаю, как им воспользоваться. В него нужно передать HWnd нашего окна и флаг SWP_NOACTIVATE. В справке MS: Requirements
Header: atlwin.h. Неужели придётся доставать этот заголовок и переписывать?

Comment: Зачем Вам извращения с FMX. На VCL все делается очень просто. FMX нужна для кроссплатформенности. А Вы напрямую хотите использовать WinAPI и, тем самым, отказаться от всей кроссплатформенности

Comment: Раньше я думал, что FMX даёт больше возможностей для работы с сенсорным экраном, но в справке написано, что у VCL поддержка жестов даже богаче будет. Сделано было не очень много, поэтому можно всё на VCL перекинуть

Comment: Не может кроссплатформенное решение давать больше возможностей, чем решение заточенное под конкретную платформу

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Для VCL Вам нужно у формы переопределить метод `CreateParams` и в поле `Params.ExStyle` добавить флаг `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE`

  ```
  procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var AParams: TCreateParams);
  begin
    inherited CreateParams(AParams);
    AParams.ExStyle := AParams.ExStyle or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
  end;
  ```
- При работе с WinAPI этот флаг нужно добавить в первый параметр функции `CreateWindowEx()`
- Для FMX, исходя из метода `TPlatformWin.CreateWindow` вы параметр `ExStyle` не переопределите

Если отказаться от кроссплатфоменности FMX, то для созданного окна можно поменять параметр `EX_STYLE` вызвав функцию `SetWindowLongPtr`

```
procedure MakeNoActivate(AWnd: HWND);
var
  LOldVal: NativeInt;
begin
  LOldVal := GetWindowLongPtr(AWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
  SetWindowLongPtr(AWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, LOldVal or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
end;
```

Получить HWND у FMX формы можно так

```
uses
  FMX.Platform.Win;
  ............
var
  LWnd: HWND
begin
  LWnd := FmxHandleToHWND(Form1.Handle);
  ................
end;
```

Comment: Это хорошее решение, если используется фреймворк VCL. В FMX такого метода у формы нет. Создавать окно через WinAPI тоже не выход, так как в таком случае не получится применить FMX

Comment: @Pivot Добавил решение для FMX

Comment: Отлично, заработало! Подсказка тем, кто будет читать эту тему: если вы выставите у формы свойство Transparency в True, данный способ для вас не сработает.

Comment: @Pivot Отметьте вопрос как верный